# Riemann zeta function, representation as a limit

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta

is it true that $$\displaystyle \zeta(s) = \ \lim_{\scriptstyle a \to 0^+}\ 1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{\textstyle -s m a } \left\lfloor e^{\textstyle(m+1)a} - e^{\textstyle m a} \right\rfloor$$ my proof :

\begin{equation}F(z) = \zeta(-\ln z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{\ln n}\end{equation}

which is convergent for $|z| < \frac{1}{e}$. now I consider the functions :

$$\tilde{F}_a(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{a \left\lfloor \textstyle \frac{\ln n}{a} \right\rfloor } = 1 + \sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{a n} \left\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{a m} \right\rfloor $$

because $\displaystyle\lim_{ a \to 0^+} a \left\lfloor \textstyle \frac{\ln n}{a} \right\rfloor = \ln n$, we get that :

$$\lim_{\scriptstyle a \to 0^+} \ \tilde{F}_a(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{\ln n} = \zeta(-\ln z)$$

---

(details)

$\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{a m} \left\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{a m} \right\rfloor $
is also convergent for $z < \frac{1}{e}$ because $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty (z^a e^a)^{m}$ is convergent for $z < \frac{1}{e}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{am} \left\{e^{a(m+1)} - e^{a m}  \right\} $ is convergent for $z < 1$.

to justify $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{a \left\lfloor \textstyle \frac{\ln n}{a} \right\rfloor } = 1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{a m} \left\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{a m} \right\rfloor $ : if $\left\lfloor \frac{\ln n}{a}  \right\rfloor = m \ne 0$ then
  $\displaystyle\frac{\ln n}{a} \in [m, m+1[ \implies n \in [ e^{am}, e^{a(m+1)}[ $ . how many different $n$'s is that ? $\left\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{am}  \right\rfloor $.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the floors around it when I wrote my answer. But why do you take the big leap to say: $$\tilde{F}_a(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{a \left\lfloor \textstyle \frac{\ln n}{a} \right\rfloor } = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{a n} \left\lfloor e^{a(n+1)} - e^{a n} \right\rfloor$$ Is there a justification for that step?

Comment: Hi, I had the justification above.

Comment: and I edited your answer, of course I saved it if you want it back. sorry that the floor function wasn't discussed more.

Comment: I tried verifying your formula numerically. The sum seems to tend to $0$, or thereabouts.

Comment: yes it's normal : it's because the first non-zero term comes farther and farther each time your $a$ decreases to $0$. you should use the formula $\tilde{F}_a(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{a \lfloor (\ln n)/ a \rfloor}$ instead to get a convergence to $\zeta(-\ln z)$ that you could verify numerically.
or maybe you could use a mix of the two : find which $\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{an}\rfloor$ are non-zero and compute the first 100 non-zero ones.

Comment: the only problem I have is with the constant $1$ appearing in $\zeta(s)$, I don't understand where it should be...

Comment: @reuns I fixed my answer after I realized that I misread it. Don't deface people's answers. I am fully capable of deleting my own answer when it is wrong.

Comment: That number of different $n$s is an estimate, no? The number of integers between $x$ and $y$ is either $\lfloor y - x\rfloor$ or $\lfloor y-x\rfloor +1$. For example, how many integers are between $x$ and $x+0.75$? It is either $0$ or $1$. @reuns

Comment: @Thomas Andrews :  
yes you are right in general but if you think of it being how many $z^{a \lfloor (\ln n) / a \rfloor} + z^{a \lfloor (\ln n + 1) / a \rfloor} + \cdots z^{a \lfloor (\ln  n + k) / a \rfloor}$ there are where $ \lfloor (\ln n) / a \rfloor = m$ ? you think it's not $\lfloor e^{a(m+1)} - e^{am} \rfloor$ ? no ok there is a problem there. thank you.
(and sorry I'm new I don't know what you can and cannot do)

Comment: Who guarantees that you may switch the sum and $\lim \limits _{a \to 0^+}$? I have *very* strong doubts about that being valid.

Comment: Indeed, the count is always wrong for $m=0$, which shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\left|e^{-nas}\left\lfloor e^{(n+1)a}-e^{na}\right\rfloor\right|&\leq e^{-nas}\left(e^{(n+1)a}-e^{na}\right)\\&=e^{-nas}e^{na}\left( e^{a}-1\right)\\&=\frac{e^a-1}{e^{na(s-1)}}
\end{align}$$

As $a\to 0$, $e^a-1\to 0$. and $e^{na(s-1)}\to 1$. So each term goes to zero as $a\to 0$.

That seems to contradict your conclusion.

Also, why is $$\sum z^{a \left\lfloor \textstyle \frac{\ln n}{a} \right\rfloor } =  \sum z^{a n} \left\lfloor e^{a(n+1)} - e^{a n} \right\rfloor?$$

That seems like a huge leap.